# AND between two list of integer in c#

Tags: c#, ilist

i need AND between two list of integer in c#
foe example if i have

```
IList<int> list1 = new List<int>(1,2,7,4);

IList<int> list2 = new List<int>(4,2,3,5);
```

and i need this output
List3 = List1 & List2;
then
list3 items is 2,4;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do [`list1.Intersect(list2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx).

Since this function calculates the intersection *set*, `Intersect` only returns distinct elements, so `{1,2,2}.Intersect({1,2}) => {1,2}`.

Comment: Since the OP is simply looking for items which are in both lists, that really isn't a "but"...

Comment: I was surprised by `Except` returning only distinct elements when I used it first, so I think it's worth mentioning that property.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this..

```
  var data = data1.Intersect(data2);
```

or

```
   List<int> c = List1.Intersect(List2).ToList();
```

Comment: Why the parse? Both lists contain `int`s. This would work if the second list contained strings.